# Content view not yet created, removeHeaderView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-asynctask

When i refresh my listview and I slide my tabactivity in the same time , i obtain a illegalstateException : Content view not yet created. I understand that the listview isn't completely created but in my code i have not found a solution to my problem.The error be found in removeHeader method.

```
public class PFrag extends ListFragment implements OnScrollListener,OnTouchListener{



ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean endProcess = false;
boolean stopLoadMore=false;

IconAdapter myAdapter;
int totalItem=0;
int last=0;
View vfoot;
View vheader;
float currentY;
float previousY;
boolean allowRefresh=false;
boolean refresh=false;
boolean activescroll=true;
boolean move=false;
AddStringTask process;


public PFrag() {
    super();

}



public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<Test> l  = new ArrayList<Test>();
    myAdapter = new IconAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row,l);
    initFoot();
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
    getListView().setOnTouchListener(this);
    setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    process=new AddStringTask();
    process.execute(0);

}




public void initFoot(){
    if(getListView().getFooterViewsCount()==0 && vfoot==null){
        vfoot = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
        getListView().addFooterView(vfoot, null, false);
        stopLoadMore=false;
        getListView().requestLayout();
        Log.v("initfoot","create");
    }
}





private class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, ArrayList<Test>>{

    protected void onPreExecute() {  

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Test> doInBackground(Integer... in) {


        ......Operation
                }

            }else{
                Log.v("status", "stoploadmore");
                stopLoadMore=true;

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            stopLoadMore=true;

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            stopLoadMore=true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Test> in) {

        cancel(true);
        if(refresh & !activescroll){
            ((IconAdapter)getListAdapter()).setEntries(new ArrayList<Test>()); 
            ((IconAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(in);
        }
        if(!refresh & activescroll)
            ((IconAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(in);
            removeHeader();
            ((IconAdapter)getListAdapter()).setNotifyOnChange(true);

        endProcess=true;

    }
}


public ArrayList<Test> displayTest(String response){ //
    .........
}


public boolean isOnTop(){ 
    ....
} 


private boolean isOnDown() {
    ....
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    Log.v("position",String.valueOf(position));
    Test Test = (Test) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(Test.getNamesociete()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),TestDetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);  
}


@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

}

public void removeFoot(){

    if(getListView().getFooterViewsCount()>0 && vfoot!=null){       
        vfoot.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE);
        ((IconAdapter)getListAdapter()).setNotifyOnChange(true);
        getListView().requestLayout();

    }

}



/* THE PROBLEM IS THIS METHOD */

public void removeHeader(){

    if(getListView().getHeaderViewsCount()>0){
        Log.v("removeheaderInIF", "ok");        
        getListView().removeHeaderView(vheader);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "delete header", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ((IconAdapter)getListAdapter()).setNotifyOnChange(true);
        getListView().requestLayout();
    }   
}


public void initHeader(){

    try{
        if(getListView().getHeaderViewsCount()==0 ){            
            vheader = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.header, null);
            getListView().addHeaderView(vheader, null, false);
            stopLoadMore=false;
            getListView().requestLayout();
            Log.v("initheader","create");           
        }       
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("headererror",String.valueOf(e));
    }   
}



@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    last = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount; 

    totalItem = totalItemCount;
    if(!stopLoadMore){

        if(last+2 >= totalItemCount && endProcess && isOnDown() ){ 

            endProcess=false;
            activescroll=true;
            vfoot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            process=new AddStringTask();
            process.execute(totalItemCount-1);

        }
    }else {
        stopLoadMore=true;

        removeFoot();       
    }
}





@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        previousY = event.getRawY();
        //Allows refresh if the first visible item is the first in the list
        allowRefresh = isOnTop();
        move=false;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        if(allowRefresh){
            if((previousY - event.getRawY()) <= -50){
                refresh = true;
                move=true;
            }
            else{
                refresh = false;
                move=false;
            }
        }

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //Refresh
        if(move){ 
            if(refresh & endProcess ){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                activescroll=false;             
                stopAsyncOperation();       
                initHeader();
                ((IconAdapter)getListAdapter()).setNotifyOnChange(true);                                
                new AddStringTask().execute(0);         
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    return false;
}



@Override
public void onPause(){

    stopAsyncOperation();
    super.onPause();
}


 private void stopAsyncOperation(){
        if( process != null){       
            if( process.getStatus().equals( AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING )){
                process.cancel( true );
            }
        }
    }

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    stopAsyncOperation();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

here the error :

> 08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at com.app.swype.ProximiteFrag.removeHeader(ProximiteFrag.java:396)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at com.app.swype.ProximiteFrag$AddStringTask.onPostExecute(ProximiteFrag.java:269)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at com.app.swype.ProximiteFrag$AddStringTask.onPostExecute(ProximiteFrag.java:1)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   08-11 21:59:51.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1186):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {

public static Fragment prof;
public static Fragment catf;
public static Fragment cof;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {



    Fragment fragment = null;
    if(arg0==0){

        if(prof==null){
            Log.v("fragment1","kk1");
            prof = new PFrag();
            return prof;
        }



    }else if (arg0==1){
        if(catf==null){
            Log.v("fragment2","kk1");
            catf = new CFrag();
            return catf;
        }

    }else if (arg0==2){

        if(cof==null){
            Log.v("fragment3","kk1");
            cof = new CoFrag();
            return cof;
        }

    }


    return prof;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 3;
}

}
```

Can you help me, please. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should move:

```
process.execute(0);
```

to onStart or onResume (which may cause it to execute more than once, but you can set a flag for that, if necessary).

Comment: It doesn't work. The code will execute corretly except I refresh my listview and in the same time i slide my tabhost. The error occurs in the postexecute method and concern removeheader method, particulary getListview() line. I don't know what i do, maybe use a synchronized method because i use more once call to asynctask and i can't use only one call to asynctask. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem just my tabactivity because there is no problem when slide to the second fragment but only to third. Apparently my first fragment is destroyed at that time. How to remedy